# How to clear back stack when navigating from side menu flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

there are 3 screens, Home. menu screen 1 and menu screen2,

when I navigate from the home screen to screen via drawer, the system keeps all stack trace,

if the android hardware back button is pressed, it pops back to the home screen, is there any way to clear the back stack when navigating from the drawer.

Please see image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While navigating to the next screen you can use `pushAndRemoveUntil` to go to the next screen while clearing the stack of routes. See the following example.

```
   Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => NextScreen()
  ), 
 ModalRoute.withName("/Home")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the stack with `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` if you are using named routes or just `pushAndRemoveUntil`

With named routes:

```
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);
```

Without named routes:

```
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()), (route) => false);
```